# How to enable inline JavaScript for LESS in Nuxt.js?

Tags: less, nuxt.js

In a Nuxt.js project, I've npm installed less and less-loader so I can have dynamic CSS for iView. However, when I try to overwrite iView's global variables, an error appears: "Inline JavaScript is not enabled. Is it set in your options?"

In Nuxt.js docs (https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build#loaders) they state they have a preconfigured less loader. less: {}, so I tried...

```
less: {
  javascriptEnabled: true
}
```

and...

```
less: {
  options: {
    javascriptEnabled: true
  }
}
```

and even...

```
less: {
  dev: {
    options: {
      javascriptEnabled: true
    }   
  }
}
```

Nuxt.js seems to ignore all of this. So how should I configure it in Nuxt.js?

Comment: Hmm, "inline javascript" normally has nothing to do with "overwrite global variables" (wherever they are). So the first Q is why you need that "inline javascript" at all. Most likely it's an XY-problem ("inline javascript" feature just allowed ancient abusive hacks in stone age versions of Less to do something simply not possible by proper language methods - hence the feature is disabled by default for a while by now, and it's 99.99% you do something really wrong if you need it).

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your `nuxt.config.js`

```
/*
 ** Build configuration
 ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/
 */
build: {
    /*
     ** You can extend webpack config here
     */
    loaders: {
        less: {
            lessOptions: {
                javascriptEnabled: true,
            },
        },
    },
},
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do it

```js
 build: {
    /*
     ** You can extend webpack config here
     */
    extend(config, { loaders: { less } }) {
      less.javascriptEnabled = true
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Nuxt 3 with typescript, adding this on `nuxt.config.ts` file worked for me

```
{ ....
vite: {
        css: {
            preprocessorOptions: {
                less: {
                    javascriptEnabled: true,
                },
            },
        },
    }
}
```